# Bullet in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I need one help i don't know how to implement bullet in `UILabel` text. I search lots of links but couldn't find the solution. Please help me. Waiting for a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need one help. We don't know what your problem is. Please help us. Waiting for you to show us what code you've written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [AliSoftware's OHAttributedLabel.](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) It is a subclass of UILabel that draws an NSAttributedString

try this:

#import "OHAttributedLabel.h"
   #import "NSAttributedString+Attributes.h"

```
OHAttributedLabel *myLabel=[[OHAttributedLabel alloc]init];
[myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 20)];
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"\u2022 list item!!!"];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)]; 
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

---

if you want to add just bullet than use this:

```
myLabel.text = @"\u2022  list item!!!!!!!!!";
```

---

[List of more unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Unicode code point for the bullet character in your string?
Try This:

myLabel.text = @"\u2022 This is a list item!";

Comment: really its a wonderful idea zink, but if i change the text color means it also affect the bulletin. is there any other possibility for custom   bulletin like star,diamond.

Comment: i have not checked that possibility yet..:) @Anamika

Comment: Thanks zink if you find means please inform me. :)

Comment: @Anamika plz check my another solution below

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12745/discussion-between-anamika-and-zink)

Answer (score 0):

hi @Anamika Try this also

```
   myLabel.text = @"\u25A0 This is a list item!";
```

and for more shapes you can chage the value from here :
http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html

Answer (score 0):

If formatting your text with bullets is a concern, I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546390/custom-bullets-from-images-on-uitextview-or-uilabel-swift) helpful. They show you how to create and align paragraphs containing bullets using storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Cmd+K on a mac will insert a bullet character.