# Custom Bullets from Images on UITextView or UILabel Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm creating an app that basically is a mobile version of a large website. This website has a certain area that lists product features. Each feature is bulleted with a unique custom image.

Is there a way to do this with swift? Essentially, create a bullet list of strings, but instead use small images for the bullet dots?

Answer (score 8):

- Make your UITextView's text type as attributed

  [image]
- Increase the Head indentation value

  [image]
- Construct your string in the following format:

  "• This is a string\n\n• This is another string, but longer and better. The number of words in this string are probably higher than the last one."
- Use Alt + 8 to type in a bullet.
- Result:[image]